# Нужен плагин Wordpress либо настроить текущий

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

На сайте стоит плагин SumoMe (Всплывающее левое меню с кнопками соцсетей)

**1.** Здесь при нажатии поделиться в facebook в левом меню(в плагине), в открывшемся окне нет картинки вообще.

http://alocubanolisandra.com/home-version-9/y_lost-on-you/

**2.** А здесь тот же самый плагин, но когда делишься этой ссылкой в FB - картинка большая и она есть :D

http://www.salserosenclave.com/video/lisandra-garcia-y-yoannis-tamayo-bailando-salsa-en-timbafest-2017/?utm_content=bufferd0249&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

**Вопросы:**

1. Где прописывается откуда плагин берет картинки?
2. Как сделать картинку больше и вообще поставить её?
3. **Или может быть** есть какой-то другой плагин, в котором можно выбирать иллюстрацию к репосту.

P.S Стоит бесплатная версия и в первом и во втором примере.

Answer (score 0):

У этого плагина нет настроек вообще. Всё, что он делает - подключает скрипт, который общается с сайтом Sumo. Все настройки картинок и всплывающих окон там, по платной подписке.